# Getting SnippetException: The following parts of the payload were not documented: error for array element

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-restdocs

Im trying to document my REST service using Spring-RestDocs here. But upto now I have not been able to document the array elements.

The test method :

```
@Test
public void listAll() throws Exception {

  MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder =
            RestDocumentationRequestBuilders.post("/diagnosis/search/{term}", "headache")
                    .header("Authorization",TestHelper.TOKEN).with(csrf());
    TestHelper.httpRequestBuilder(requestBuilder, new SearchEntity("5b55aabd0550de0021097b64",Arrays.asList("PL01", "PL02"),true));

    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder)
            .andDo(DiagnosisDocument.documentSearchTerm())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();
    MockHttpServletResponse response = result.getResponse();
    System.out.println(response.getContentAsString());
    assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK.value(), response.getStatus());
}
```

The documenting method :

```
 public static ResultHandler documentSearchTerm() {
    return document("search-diagnosis", pathParameters(
   parameterWithName("term").description("Term")),

   requestFields(fieldWithPath("clinicId").description("bla bla")),

   requestFields(fieldWithPath("isGlobalSearch").description("bla bla")),

   requestFields(subsectionWithPath("[].planIds").description("bla bla")),
   responseAPI(true));

}
```

The SearchEntity class :

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class DiagnosisSearchEntiry {

   private String clinicId;
   private List<String> planIds = new ArrayList<>();
   private boolean isGlobalSearch;

}
But in this implementation, im getting following exception and the test fails.

org.springframework.restdocs.snippet.SnippetException: The following parts of the payload were not documented:
{
  "planIds" : [ "PL01", "PL02" ],
  "globalSearch" : true
}
```

Is there any particular reason im getting this error? Am I documenting it wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

When `DiagnosisSearchEntiry` is serialised to JSON, the `isGlobalSearch` field is mapped to a field in the JSON named `globalSearch`. Your request field path needs to be updated to reflect this:

```
requestFields(fieldWithPath("globalSearch").description("bla bla"))
```

The path `[].planIds` is looking for an array of objects with `planIds` fields. It would match JSON like this:

```
[
  {
    "planIds": ["PL01", "PL02"]
  },
  {
    "planIds": ["PL03", "PL04"]
  }
]
```

Your JSON that is being documented is structured like this:

```
{
  "clinicId": "the clinic id",
  "planIds": [ "PL01", "PL02" ],
  "globalSearch": true  
}
```

To document the array of plan IDs, the path should be `planIds.[]`:

```
requestFields(subsectionWithPath("planIds.[]").description("bla bla"))
```